# Avoid users from editing tables / columns in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I would like to lock users from accessing tables and columns within an SQL Server database. As with MS Access and SQL Server CE databases, you can assign a database level password so that no one can open the database and alter any tables, etc. by me. Is there a way I can do this with an SQL Server database (`.mdf`)? I currently create my database programmatically when the user installs my application. I tried the following code below but I was still able to open the database in SSMS and alter the database.

```
sSQL = "ALTER DATABASE COLORS SET RESTRICTED_USER"
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = sSQL
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I started SSMS, the database was named [COLORS (Restricted User)] but I was able to open and alter the table.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you connecting to the server? If you're using Windows Authentication and you're a local Administrator then you have full access to everything. You can restrict access to other users by using SQL Authentication with suitably restricted `LOGIN` and `USER` objects.

Comment: Access's whole-database passwords are used to encrypt the entire database, however in SQL Server a user who can view the MDF files on disk can still view the data - if you want to encrypt the SQL Server database there's a whole load of steps to go through and you're better-off posting a new question for that topic in particular.

Comment: If the database is created in the context of the user, then the user will have db_owner permissions and so be able to view and edit any data.

Comment: I'm connecting to the database using Windows Authentication (for now). I can't believe that I can't lockout users from altering tables or columns within those tables of my database. So, what I'm hearing is that every developer's database in the world is exposed to anyone who has access to the SQL Server? Seriously?

Comment: @tropicwhisper No, that’s not true. As I said, you can encrypt SQL Server’s databases. But I want to stress that very few people should have access to a database server anyway (I.e. sysadmins) so there’s no security risk. If you’re using SQL Server Express for an on-prem database then yes, the structure and content of the databases will be visible to anyone with access to that computer unless it’s encrypted - but if it’s encrypted then the application code will have the password and that password can *and will* be found eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to database using Windows Authentication, You are able to access database.

If a user is a Windows Administrator of Server, assume that they own everything on server (including SQL Server). With Windows Administrator rights it is trivial to bypass any targeted protection you apply. If you don't trust someone (users), don't give them Windows Administrator rights.

Create a **SQL authentication** for them [Creating a user and granting table level permissions](https://support.chartio.com/knowledgebase/granting-table-level-permissions-in-sql-server)

You can give specific object rights to users, one way to do this is like

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT , UPDATE ON TABLENAME TO USER_NAME
```

for granting object permissions: [GRANT Object Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Alternatively you can create a database role and assign table rights to this role then attach role to user.

```
CREATE ROLE <RoleName>
GO
GRANT INSERT, SELECT , UPDATE ON <TABLENAME> TO  <RoleName>
GO
sp_addrolemember <TEST> , <UserName>
```